# 442 Unprocessable Entity With Fastapi

Tags: python, model, fastapi, pydantic

I want to serve my model some data from form data, i used pydantic to validate the data and tried converting the returned value to dataframe for prediction. but am getting this error "Unprocessable Entity" when it is supposed to return the predicted value.

[Here is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORwyi.png)

[this is the Pydantic validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLKjO.png)
[This is the other parts of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeI7W.png)

''' app = FastAPI(title='Placement Analytics', version='1.0',
description='Lightgbm model is used for prediction')

```
class Data(BaseModel):
    oldRoad: float 
    onRoadNow: float 
    years: float
    km: float
    rating: float
    condition: float
    economy: float
    topSpeed: float
    horsePower: float
    torque: float


@app.get('/home')
def read_home():
    """
     Home endpoint which can be used to test the availability of the application.
     """
    return {'message': 'System is healthy'}

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(data: Data):
    data_dict = data
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([data_dict])
    pickle_in = open("predict.pkl","rb")
    classifier = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    prediction = classifier.predict(df2)

    return {"prediction":prediction}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1",port=8000, reload=True, debug=True)'''
```

Comment: You need to show your request as well. The error message is saying you didnt send a value for "years" in the http body

Comment: Yep!! It worked but am getting A new error " ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'oldRoad'"    which i have traced the problem but dont know how to deal with it.  The  dataframe created doesnt sees the column names as values because the conversion somehow seperated the column names from their values. Any idea how i can solve that.